# Google Map Marker + JQuery: Change icon

Tags: asp.net, jquery

If I already displayed a google map marker.

How could I change its icon using Jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery isn't really going to help... all you need is plain Javascript to interact with the google api.  How was the map marker displayed?  You need a way of referencing it.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks. 

I just have found a method which is useful: marker.setImage(..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Google Maps API has supported method to setImage for marker. I get this code from Google Code PlayGround (http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#custom_marker_image_v3)

```
function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var image = 'http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/images/beachflag.png';
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856);
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
}
```